# Calculate linear commission - Looking for a formula

Tags: r, linear-programming, algebra

Using R, Is there a formula that can help me calculate a sales commission based on this condition. For eg:

If the growth (in %) is between 5% and 7% then the salesman will receive a commission which will be linear from 10% to 12.5%

The variables:

```
TargetAmt<-100
Earned<-105.6
PctGrowth<-((Earned-TargetAmt)/TargetAmt)*100
PctGrowth
```

> 5.6

Therefore, I now need to calculate his commission, which will be linear from 10% to 12.5%.

I can do this manually by calculating  slope of the line. However, how can I do this in R?

Comment: Your points are (x1, y1)=(0.05, 0.10) and (x2, y2)=(0.07, 0.125).  Just use the point-slope form of a line:  y-y1=m*(x-x1), where m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) lm** For a growth of 5.6% the commission is 10.6%

```
growth <- c(5, 7)
commission <- c(10, 12.5)

fit <- lm(commission ~ growth)
predict(fit, list(growth = 5.6))
##     1 
## 10.75
```

**1a)** Alternately, we can get the formula from the linear regression and then just apply it ourself.  In this case the slope is 1.25 and the intercept is 3.75:

```
> fit
Call:
lm(formula = commission ~ growth)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       growth  
       3.75         1.25
```

so the commision is the 1.25 times the growth as a percentage plus 3.75 percentage points, i.e. 1.25 * 5.6 + 3.75 = 10.75 .

**2) approx** Another way is to use `approx` like this:

```
approx(growth, commission, xout = 5.6)$y
## [1] 10.75
```

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck. That helped heaps.

Comment: This is really nice and simple, just one thing, OP was asking for a commission from 10 - 12.5. so you make sure to change commission <- c(10, 12) to commission <- c(10, 12.5)

Comment: I will be using the `approx` function. Its the most straigh-forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative Solution**

**Finding the equation of the line**

Using y = mx + c:

```
m = (0.125 - 0.1)/(0.07-0.05)
m = 0.025/0.02
m = 1.25
```

Substitute 0.1 (10%) and 0.05 (5%) into the equation to get c

```
y = 1.25x + c
0.1 = (1.25 * 0.05) + c
0.1 - (1.25 * 0.05) = c
c = 0.0375
```

we now have our equation for the line:

```
y = 1.25x + 0.0375
```

**The code**:

```
TargetAmt <- 100
Earned <- 105.6

profitAsDecimal = (Earned/TargetAmt) - 1
commission = (1.25 * profitAsDecimal) + 0.0375
commissionAsDecimal = (1.25 * profitAsDecimal) + 0.0375
```

So for the growth of 5.6 your commissionAsDecimal would be 0.1075. multiply by 100 to get the percentage of 10.75.

This answer will give you a result linear from 5% to 7% equaling 10% to 12.5%. The answer above is going from 10% to 12%

Comment: Thank you. You are right. He had a typo. I knew the concept. I wanted the formula in R. Thank you for your help.